# python 3d funcanimation not plotting

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to pass a bunch(about 300) of 4 column panda df. each of these 300 df's are a frame in the animation. does anyone know why nothing is plotting? im new to funcanimation and im a little lost

my first function is suppose to be called to make each frame... but i dont know how to use offsets... not sure if im initializing the animation correctly because i used a zeros frame. i keep printing scatters the line after offsets but its always 0

```
"""
    PIPELINE
    1. MAKE FIGURE WINDOW
    2. CREATE AN INITIALIZATION FUNCTION
    3. CREATE A FUNCTION THAT PLOTS EACH FRAME
    4. USE FUNCANIM to animare

"""


# IMPORTS
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import os

def animate_scatters(iteration, data, scatters):
"""
Update the data held by the scatter plot and therefore animates it.

Returns:
    list: List of scatters (One per element) with new coordinates
   !!!!!!!!! ONLY DOES ONE FRAME AT A TIME!!!!!!!!
"""

#now we need to go into the directory and read the files
directory_of_embeddings = sorted([item for item in os.listdir(data) if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(data,item)) and ".csv" in item])  # make of list of embeddings that excludes any other file type lis .DS_store
#print(directory_of_embeddings)

for file in directory_of_embeddings:
    print(file)
    embedding=pd.read_csv(data+'/'+str(file),delimiter=',')
    print(embedding)
    #embedding.drop(columns=embedding.columns[0], axis=1, inplace=True)
    embedding.columns=["X","Y","Z","JD"]
    print(embedding)
    scatters[iteration]._offsets3d = (embedding.X,embedding.Y,embedding.Z)
"""

def main(data, save=True):
    """
    Creates the 3D figure and animates it with the input data.

    Args:
        data (list): List of the data positions at each iteration.
        save (bool): Whether to save the recording of the animation. (Default to False).
    """

    # Attaching 3D axis to the figure
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)

    # Initialize scatters
    """make 0's data frame for initialization"""
    scatters=[pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((1000,3)))]
    
    # Number of iterations/frames
    if os.path.isdir(data)==1:
        print('READY!')

    iterations=290
    # Setting the axes properties
    #ax.set_xlim3d([-50, 50])
    ax.set_xlabel('X')

    #ax.set_ylim3d([-50, 50])
    ax.set_ylabel('Y')

    #ax.set_zlim3d([-50, 50])
    ax.set_zlabel('Z')

    ax.set_title('3D self Example')

    # Provide starting angle for the view.
    #ax.view_init(25, 10)

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate_scatters, iterations, fargs=(data, scatters),interval=5000000000, blit=False, repeat=False)
    

    if save:
        Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
        writer = Writer(fps=30, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
        ani.save('3d-iris.mp4', writer=writer)

    

data = '/Users/melanietu/Desktop/IRIS/3d'
main(data, save=True)
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're working with?

Comment: yes.....i tried to.......im a little new to stack overflow

Comment: code added.....